# Wordpress .htaccess file gives issues with subdirectory

Tags: htaccess

I have a WordPress installation in the root and a subdirectory, which contains a `index.html` file.

This file doesn't give me proper display as what it is supposed to when I access it. But when I rename the `.htaccess` file on root (WordPress main installation), this index file in the subdirectory shows up as it is supposed to. But this makes WordPress non functional.

I have no `.htaccess` file in my subfolder.

These are the contents of my `.htaccess`:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What is in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: What does this mean, in detail, "This file doesn't give me proper display as what it is supposed to when I access it"? What do you get?

Comment: my page should show all its content as in this link 
http://billmath.com/smart/

but is shows as in this one instead
http://jump2health.com/smart/

Comment: If you compare the markup (View Source) of both of those pages the output is the same as near as I can tell. The likely problem is that your Javascript is failing for some reason, perhaps a bad path. I did not analyze it very thoroughly.

Comment: But if I remove .htaccess file in the root folder this java script works. I didnt touch the file in the folder.